# Proof regarding basic properties of sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, solution-verification

[image]

We've just started learning sequences and I was faced with this question. I have a strong feeling that I'm missing something and that I'm over simplifying things as these questions almost seem trivial to the point I'm not sure how to correctly prove them..

**A.** True

Assume $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }$ converges to some $L∈R$.

Then as $\{a_n | n∈N\}$ = $\{b_n | n∈N\}$ for every $n∈N$

$(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }=(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }=L$

Similarly, if $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }$ converges

$(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }=(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }=L$.

**B.** True

Assume $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }$ converges to some $L∈R$.

As $\{n∈N | a_n ≠ b_n\}$ is bounded from above, there exists $M∈N$ such that for every $n≥M$ we have

$a_n = b_n$

Therefore $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }=(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }=L$.

Similarly if $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }$ converges, there exists $M∈N$ such that for every $n≥M$ we have

$b_n = a_n$

Therefore $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }=(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }=L$.

**C.** False.

Counter example:

$\{a_n\} = \frac{1}{n}$ for every $n∈N$

$\{b_n\} = Z^{+}$

We've seen in recitation that $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty } = 0$. But $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }=∞$, and therefore diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A)$ is false : take $a_1=-1$, and $a_n=1$ for all $n\geq 2$ and $b_n=(-1)^n$ for all $n\geq 1$ for a counter example.

$B)$ is indeed true, but your justification is strange (what means $(a_n)=(b_n)=L$?) Indeed, $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\geq M$ for some $M\in \mathbb N$. From here, obviously $(a_n)$ converges if and only if $(b_n)$ converges.

$C)$ is true (I even don't understand your counter-example). If $(a_n)$ converges, since $(b_n)$ is increasing, then $(b_n)$ converges as well. If $(b_n)$ converges, then, by squeeze theorem, $(a_n)$ converges as well.

Comment: Nice catch, I misread it.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused about the notation of (A) and as I was about to ask you how your example works it hit me. :)